# How to add labels next to doughnut chart angular-chartjs

Tags: angularjs, charts

I would like to add labels next to the chart on the outside, rather than tooltips, which is the current default. How can I do that? I found this question [How to add labels into Chart.js canvas plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590301/how-to-add-labels-into-chart-js-canvas-plugin) but it's old and the chartjs code is not the same anymore. I would love some help adapting it please!

Answer (score 0):

Hook into the chart-create event in your controller:

```
scope.$on('chart-create', function(event, chart) {
    var legend = chart.generateLegend();
    $(`#${chart.options.legendId}`).append(legend);
});
```

Set `legendId` in the options to the id of the element you want to have contain the legends:

```
options = {
    legendId: 'test-pie-legend'
    ...
```

I also had to do some CSS work to make the colors show correctly:

```
.chart-legend li span {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: .5em;
}

.chart-legend li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.chart-legend {
    margin-top: 3em; 
}
```

Of course your legend holder element has to have this class:

```
<div id="test-pie-legend" class="chart-legend"></div>
```