# How to add symbols in angular charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, ionic-framework, chart.js, angular-chart

I am currently building an Ionic mobile prototype with mock JSON data, hardcoded in the code. I am using [angular charts](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) to build my charts.

Looking at the Doughnut chart example, you can see label/data when hovering over it. How do I add a percent sign after the value?

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590301/how-to-add-labels-into-chart-js-canvas-plugin) but the Chart.js source code has changed quite a bit since then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By simply inserting chart option in your html markup and specifying template for your tooltip will work for you.

```
<canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut"
  chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels"
        chart-options="{tooltipTemplate: '<%=label%>:<%=value%>%'}">
</canvas>
```

Here is the working [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKQKLB) for same.